# How to set the size of the bit map image which displays QR Code

Tags: c#, bitmapimage

I have to display the QR code in the web page which I will get it from the ViewData which holds the bitmap image (50*50) address as follows

```cs
QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
var qrGeneratedDateTime =Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now);    
var code = Convert.ToString(valueVariable+ qrGeneratedDateTime);

QRCodeData qrCodedata = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(code, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
QRCode qrCode = new QRCode(qrCodedata);
Bitmap bitMap= new Bitmap(50,50);
using (bitMap = qrCode.GetGraphic(20))
{
    bitMap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
    ViewData["QRCodeImage"] = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
}
```

But when QR code image displayed in the web page which had the small table (before QR code display)which houses the QR code image, took almost full window size table which indicates that bit map image took a default image size; What is the error in my code. I want the QR code image of my own height and width.

Comment: `in the web page` where's *that* code? Did you set the size in the `img` tag?

Comment: instead of qrCode.GetGraphic(20) you can try  qrCode.GetGraphic(2)

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Gave auto size

Comment: @Seckin Celik  : willnt GetGraphic(2) reduce the no. of details of qr code ?

Comment: @krity meaning? Post your HTML code. *Don't* leave the size to chance if you want it to be a specific size.

Comment: @krity I have got mine without having any problem. Have you test it though?

Answer (score -1):

I do this to resize QR/Bar code:

```
        private System.Drawing.Image ResizeImage(System.Drawing.Image image, int size)
        {
            System.Drawing.Image resizedImage = new Bitmap(size, size);

            using (Graphics graphicsHandler = Graphics.FromImage(resizedImage))
            {
                graphicsHandler.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                graphicsHandler.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, size, size);
            }

            return resizedImage;
        }
```

Comment: That's no different than what the OP did. Create a 50x50 bitmap and draw on it